# Posterior, prior, likelihood exercise

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

I'm trying to solve a, what is supposed to be, a simple exercise regarding finding posterior.

Exercise is following:

Assume you are making repeated independent experiments with a probability of success θ in each experiment. Initially, you make 12 experiments, of which 9 are successful.

a) Using a prior for $\theta$ that is uniform on the interval $[0, 1]$, what is the posterior for $\theta$ given the results of the 12 experiments?

I'm new to this, but my solution so far is:

- I know that posterior $\propto$ likelihood $\times$ prior, that is  $\pi (\theta | data) \propto \pi (data | \theta) \pi(\theta)$
- I've not completely understood posterior, likelihood and prior in detail. But I do know that Beta and Binomial belongs together, for which I also noticed that $\theta \sim unif[0,1]$ is equivalent to $\theta \sim Beta(1,1)$ and since we are dealing with experiments with two possible outcomes, I think of Binomial distribution.
- With these things noticed I don't know how to proceed with the calculation of $\pi (data | \theta) \pi(\theta)$

Would anyone like to help me out?

Comment: Can you write down the likelihood of the data given a probability of success $\theta$?

Comment: I assume the likelihood of the data would be a data which follows a binomial distribution where we want $k=9$ successes out of $n=12$ trials, with a probability of $\theta$?

So something like ${9\choose 12} \theta^9(1-\theta)^{3}$

Comment: Exactly, I'll write my answer based on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in the post and the comments, here are the prior and likelihood functions:

- $\pi(\theta) = 1$ (on the interval $(0, 1)$).
- $\pi(\mathrm{data}\mid\theta) = \binom{12}{9}\theta^9(1 - \theta)^{12 - 9}$.

Now if you multiply them, you should get (up to a multiplicative constant) the posterior distribution:

$$\pi(\theta \mid \mathrm{data}) \propto 1 \cdot\binom{12}{9}\theta^9(1 - \theta)^{12 - 9} \propto \theta^9(1 - \theta)^3.$$

Remember, this is a distribution for the probability of success $\theta$, so it is supported on the interval $(0, 1)$.

The question is now: can you think of a continuous distribution on the interval $(0, 1)$ such that its density function, up to a multiplicative constant, looks like the posterior expression derived above?

Alternatively, you can take the expression $\theta^9(1 - \theta)^3$ and integrate it from 0 to 1. This will tell you what the multiplicative constant should be.

---

As mentioned in the comments, the expression $\theta^9(1 - \theta)^3$ looks a lot like the PDF of the Beta distribution with $a=10$ and $b=4$. And in fact, since we know that the posterior PDF has to integrate to 1, we can conclude that the posterior is indeed $Beta(10, 4)$.

An important aside: the fact that we get $\pi(\theta \mid \mathrm{data}) \propto \pi(\mathrm{data}\mid\theta) \pi(\theta)$ and not an equality is one of the main reasons why Bayesian statistics is computationally difficult. We only know the posterior distribution up to a constant, and we often need to learn about this distribution without ever computing the constant.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think I understand the last question. Is not the posterior already computed, or does it need further calculations?

Comment: @zzz__ Recall that a posterior should be a density, and a density should integrate to one. The expression we have for the posterior doesn't integrate to one.

Comment: Okey, so either I Integrate $\int_0^1 C*\theta^9(1-\theta)^3 d\theta$ = 1 and solve C which gives me the density as some C where density is $C*\theta^9(1-\theta)^3 d\theta$.

or I look into different distributions and look for something that looks like that? The PDF for Beta looks similar, where the nominator looks identical so my expression, but its also divided by Beta($\alpha$$\beta$)?

Comment: @zzz__ Both approaches are fine. But as you point out, the expression looks like the PDF for Beta (up to a constant), and we know that PDF will integrate to 1. Therefore, you can simply infer what the constant $C$ should be from this fact. In other words, you have just concluded that the posterior distribution is Beta(10, 4).

Comment: Hmm, I don't think I get this last part. Google says that the PDF for beta is $\frac{\theta^{a-1}(1-\theta)^{b-1}}{B(a,b)}$ which should integrate to 1. But my expression is only the nominator, from the exercise, which does not integrate to 1? How can the posterior distribution be Beta(10,4) and integrate to 1 at the same time? Or what part am I not getting right?

Comment: @zzz__ Exactly. So the constant we need in order for $\theta^9(1-\theta)^3$ to be a PDF is $1/B(a,b)$, where $a = 10$ and $b = 4$. Let me edit my response given our discussion here.

Comment: So the $B(a,b)$ is to be considered the constant, and the whole expression as the posterior density? Thanks a lot for your help Turgeon!

Comment: You've stated that the posterior is Beta(10,4), am I still not getting this, should not the posterior by the whole expression divided by Beta(10,4)?

Comment: @zzz__ Right, that's a confusing thing. There is the beta distribution, which is often denoted Beta(a, b). This is what I'm referring to here. But there is also the beta function, also often denoted Beta(a,b) but I prefer the notation B(a,b).

So the posterior distribution is a beta distribution Beta(a,b). The posterior PDF is the expression $\theta^{a-1}(1-\theta)^{b-1}/B(a,b)$. Hope this helps!

Comment: I understand! Thanks once again, appreciate your help a lot Turgeon!!